# Header files for Mongoose' 'plugin' method (extending via .methods and .statics)

Tags: mongoose, typescript, passport.js, definitelytyped, mongoose-plugins

I'm trying to create Typescript header files for a [script](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose) that extends my Mongoose-model by using the .plugin method. Current signature from [Mongoose header-files](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts#L111):

```
export class Schema {
   // ...
   plugin(plugin: (schema: Schema, options?: Object) => void, 
                   options?: Object): Schema;
   // ...
}
```

Some actual code from [Mongoose-lib](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js#L749):

```
/**
 * Registers a plugin for this schema.
 *
 * @param {Function} plugin callback
 * @param {Object} [opts]
 * @see plugins
 * @api public
 */

Schema.prototype.plugin = function (fn, opts) {
  fn(this, opts);
  return this;
};
```

Then my own model, extending the [plugin](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose);

```
import passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose')
// ...
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
});
// ...
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
    usernameField: "email",
    usernameLowerCase: true
});
```

Snippet from [passport-local-mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose) source:

```
module.exports = function(schema, options) {
   // ...   
   schema.methods.setPassword = function (password, cb) {
      // ...
   }

   schema.statics.authenticate = function() {
      // ...
   }
   // ...
}
```

Problem occurs in my main app.js

```
   // ...

   userSchema.authenticate()                // <<< Typescript error, undefined

   //   OR

   userSchemaInstance.setPassword(pass, cb) // <<< Typescript error, undefined
```

The problem is that .authenticate etc. were dynamically added through [.methods](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/master/lib/passport-local-mongoose.js#L83) and [.statics](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/master/lib/passport-local-mongoose.js#L177) ...

I can't find a way to model this in the typescript header files.

I tried generics and stuff, but I can't (dynamic) apply the provide plugin-methods back to the original model. I also tried `plugin` returning generic `T extends S & P` (where S extends Schema from first argument and P = plugin itself).   No luck :-(

Any suggestions or examples how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare interfaces in `passport-local-mongoose.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
    // methods
    export interface PassportLocalDocument extends Document {
        setPassword(pass: string, cb: (err: any) => void);
    }

    // statics
    export interface PassportLocalModel<T extends PassportLocalDocument> extends Model<T> {
        authenticate(username: string, password: string, cb: (err: any) => void);
    }

    // plugin options
    export interface PassportLocalOptions {
        usernameField?: string;
        usernameLowerCase?: boolean;
    }

    export interface PassportLocalSchema extends Schema {
        plugin(
            plugin: (schema: PassportLocalSchema, options?: PassportLocalOptions) => void,
            options?: PassportLocalOptions): Schema;
    }

    export function model<T extends PassportLocalDocument>(
        name: string,
        schema?: PassportLocalSchema,
        collection?: string,
        skipInit?: boolean): PassportLocalModel<T>;
}

declare module 'passport-local-mongoose' {
    import mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var _: (schema: mongoose.Schema, Options?: Object) => void;
    export = _;
}
```

Use it in your `app.ts`:

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
import passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

interface UserDocument extends mongoose.PassportLocalDocument {
    email: string,
    password: string;
}

var userSchema = <mongoose.PassportLocalSchema>new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
    usernameField: 'email',
    usernameLowerCase: true
});

var User = mongoose.model<UserDocument>('User', userSchema);
User.authenticate(userName, pass, cb);

var user = new User();
user.setPassword(newPass, cb);
```

Comment: want to add this file to DefinitelyTyped repository https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped? Could be a great help for other Typescripters

Comment: I think the above is outdated as DefinatelyTyped now has a definition: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/passport-local-mongoose/passport-local-mongoose.d.ts, which seems to work a bit differently to the above.